# Ubuntu 20.04 No Wifi adapter found and doesn't detect USB tether

Tags: wireless, broadcom, ubuntu-drivers, modprobe

I know there are similar questions. but their command output is different to mine and did not work for me. I have installed Ubuntu on my flash drive and i have used it for more than a year.

**Cause of problem:**
I was turning the wifi switch(`ctrl + F2`) on and off repeatedly when i accidentally disconnected the usb that the os is installed on. when restarting i can not connect to wifi; it says `No Wifi Adapter Found`. i tried USB tether but that is not detected. wifi and usb tether works when using the live usb that i installed Ubuntu from. I don't currently have access to broadband so i haven't tried the ethernet connection.

I am not able to connect to the internet so i am running all the commands below from the live usb `chrooting` to the real system.

1.
`rfkill unblock all`
`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`  says networking command not found so i changed 'networking' to 'network-manager'
`sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`  throws no such file
`sudo reboot`

2.
`sudo apt remove broadcom-sta-dkms bcmwl-kernel-source`
`sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer`

3.
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`

**some Info**
pc model: Dell Inspiron n5050
Bios: bios not UEFI
no option to enable/disable wireless connection from boot.
No option to secure boot.

modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf file:
 `# wl module from Broadcom conflicts with ssb`
 `# We must blacklist the following modules:`
`blacklist b43`
`blacklist b43legacy`
`blacklist b44`   tried commenting out this but no luck
`blacklist bcma`  tried commenting out this but no luck
`blacklist brcm80211`
`blacklist brcmsmac`
`blacklist ssb`
`install wl /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install wl $CMDLINE_OPTS`

modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf file:
 `# wl module from Broadcom conflicts with the following modules:`
`blacklist b43`
`blacklist b43legacy`
`blacklist b44`
`blacklist bcma`
`blacklist brcm80211`
`blacklist brcmsmac`
`blacklist ssb`

some command outputs:
1.
`lshw -C network`
clipped output:
`*-network description: Wireless interface product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries physical id: 0 bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0 logical name: wlp9s0b1 version: 01 serial: 64:27:37:da:03:29 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic firmware=610.812 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11 resources: irq:19 memory:f7d00000-f7d03fff`

2. `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`
   Output: `09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313   802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)` 
   `Subsystem: Dell BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0012]`
   `Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge`
   `Kernel modules: bcma`
   `0: hci0: Bluetooth`
   `Soft blocked: no`
   `Hard blocked: no`
   `1: phy0: Wireless LAN`
   `Soft blocked: no`
   `Hard blocked: no`

**Note this line in the above output**
`Kernel modules: bcma`    other outputs i saw online `Kernel modules: bcma,wl`

3. `sudo modprobe wl`
   output: `ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='wl' modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg) modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:990 command_do() Error running install command '/sbin/modprobe --ignore-install wl ' for module wl: retcode 1 modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Invalid argument`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try `code sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf && sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf` Then reboot